# Issue in WSDL2Java

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I am trying to use `wsdl2java` utility to generate POJOs. It's working fine for complete WSDL file. However, if a WSDL has

```
<wsdl:import>
```

it fails. What's the way to generate POJOs from such WSDLs?

Sample WSDL is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:bns0="urn:OFTCoreLookupDataWsd/OFTCoreLookupDataConfig/document" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="OFTCoreLookupDataWsd" targetNamespace="urn:OFTCoreLookupDataWsd">
<wsdl:import location="https://TARGET:443/OFTCoreLookupData/OFTCoreLookupDataConfig/bindings?wsdl&style=document" namespace="urn:OFTCoreLookupDataWsd/OFTCoreLookupDataConfig/document"/>
<wsdl:service name="OFTCoreLookupData">
<wsdl:port name="OFTCoreLookupDataConfigPort_Document" binding="bns0:OFTCoreLookupDataConfigBinding">
<soap:address location="https://TARGET:443/OFTCoreLookupData/OFTCoreLookupDataConfig?style=document"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The error I am getting is:

> The reference to entity "style" must end with the ';' delimiter.

This is on

```
<wsdl:import>
```

location in WSDL. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a guess but you may need to replace the `&` character in the location attributes URL value with `&amp;` to have a proper WSDL document. The problem is probably due to XML parsing and not the WSDL itself. Here is how it would look:

```
<wsdl:import location="https://TARGET:443/OFTCoreLookupData/OFTCoreLookupDataConfig/bindings?wsdl&amp;style=document" namespace="urn:OFTCoreLookupDataWsd/OFTCoreLookupDataConfig/document"/>
```

Comment: This worked. It removed the delimiter error. But now i am getting "IOException:Stream closed" error

Comment: Sorry but can't help with that one. I'm a .NET developer and have worked with WSDL before so I noticed your encoding issue. You'll be better off starting a new question specifically about your IOExeception. Good luck!! :)